# Как с помощью библиотеки Хроно сделать так чтобы время было в секундах а не в нано

Tags: c++, время

Здравствуйте такой вопрос : нужно заcечь время за которое выполняется функция сортировки делал через хроно . Дело в том что время показывается только через наносекунды хотел сделать просто через секунды то показывало ноль вот мой код

```
auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
sort2(A, N);
auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
int elapsed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds> (end - begin).count();
cout << elapsed << "нс   ";
cout << endl;
```

Comment: chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>

Comment: Ну а что вы хотите, если там наносекунды, и при делении из них не набирается целой секунды?

Answer (score 1):

Так как там только целое количество тех или иных единиц, рекомендовал бы переходить к плавающей точке:

```
double elapsed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds> (end - begin).count()*1e-9;
```

Так не лучше?